# How to texture paint large objects while retaining high quality paint

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm new to Blender and have tried to make myself a large cave model. After I've finished it, I tried texture painting it and am successfully able to, but it seems the quality of the texture being painted to the mesh (im using Stencil) is a bit blurry. I tried the same image on a smaller object and sure enough, it painted very well.

Based on my research, it has to do with how my UV is unwrapped. If I unwrapped a small object, it is unwrapped looking large on the UV map (sorry if wrong terminology) and paints in high quality. The problem is for large objects, when you unwrap them, the islands are forced to be small (even with seams) in the UV map or else they wouldn't all fit in the UV Map.

What can I do about this? Is it possible to have multiple UV maps so I can put each island on their own UV map? Or am I doing it wrong and there is the right way to do it?

Comment: For that last part of the question, look up the new UDIM features for creating multiple image mappings across an object.

Answer (score 1):

UV mapping is the way you can define how the faces of a 3d mesh are placed and projected in a 2d plane (texture).

You can increase, decrease, stretch the area in the UV mapping.

You can also attach a huge "image texture" to the mesh (UV mapping helps to map 3d mesh to 2d texture), so when you paint an object you won't loose any detail.

The bigger the texture is, the mode big the UV area should be

(in newest version of blender, you can have different UV MAP / texture with different pixel density --> check this article+video: [new-udim-texture-painting](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/12/18/blender-2-82-new-udim-texture-painting-features/), bu probabily you won't need it)

here you can check how different faces have different size as UV MAP
[image]